# focus function is not working on Safari Browser

Tags: jquery

I am working on a web app, and i ma trying to upload documents. but the document saving code is not executing becuase of focus function is not working. Please guide me how i can solve the issue.

Here is my code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') === -1) {
    // Safari is running
    console.log("Safari is running");
    $(document).on("focus", ".docs_field", function(){
        console.log("CHECKING");
        var base_url = $('#base_url').val();
        var _token = $('#_token').val();
        var activeField = $(this);
        var lead_id = $("#lead_id").val();
        var file = this.files[0];
        var ids = $(this).attr('name');
        var formData = new FormData();
        
        formData.append('lead_id', lead_id);
        formData.append('ids', ids);
        
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function() {
            formData.append('file_data', reader.result);
            
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', base_url+"auto_save_doc.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', _token);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                console.log("response", xhr.responseText);
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var docu_ids = result['document_id'];
                activeField.next().val(docu_ids);
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        };
    });
        
} else {
    console.log("Safari is not running");
}
```

I want that  ajax call should work with both google and safari browser.

Comment: `focus` is an event that does not bubble

Comment: expensive information. Thanks

Comment: @Terry i am going to deposit it in bank